# How to add item in Setting->Display->Wallpaper->Choose wallpaper from?

Tags: android, wallpaper

I want to add item in Setting->Display->Wallpaper->Choose wallpaper from.

How to do and Please tell me,thanks..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is a list of Activities, so first ensure you have created an [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) that will be the entry point into your app from that list.

Then, open up `AndroidManifest.xml` and add the following [`<intent-filter>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) to the Activity you want to be listed:

```
<activity android:label="@string/activity_label" ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The text of added item will be the label of the `Activity` (`android:label="@string/activity_label"`)